# dateTime.format returns incorrect value for time

Tags: apex, datetime, date

I have below apex code.

```
Datetime myCSTTimeNow      = Datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss','America/Chicago');
Datetime rightNowAsCST     = Datetime.valueOfGmt(myCSTTimeNow);
Integer currentCSThour     = integer.valueOf(rightNowAsCST.format('hh'));
Integer currentCSTminutes  = integer.valueOf(rightNowAsCST.format('mm'));
Time currentTime           = Time.newInstance(currentCSThour, currentCSThour, 00, 00);
String currentDayOfTheWeek = rightNowAsCST.format('EEEE');


System.debug('rightNowAsCST '+ rightNowAsCST);
System.debug('current time split '+ string.valueOf(rightNowAsCST).split(' '));
System.debug('currentCSThour '+ currentCSThour);
System.debug('currentCSTminutes '+ currentCSTminutes);
System.debug('currentTime '+ currentTime);
```

below is the output of the above code

[image]

I have also tried changing

```
Integer currentCSThour     = integer.valueOf(rightNowAsCST.format('hh'));
```

to

```
Integer currentCSThour     = integer.valueOf(rightNowAsCST.format('hh','America/Chicago'));
```

but I still get the output as 2 instead of 7.

I am getting the expected value when I print rightNowAsCST it converts my time with CST time but when I use format or even use split to fetch the time then it changes the time value (7:22 with 2:22)and because of the incorrect time it prints incorrect day also.
I would highly appreciate it if someone helps me to understand this sorcery!

Answer (score 1):

@gs650x : Please note that format() method

**Converts the date to the local time zone and returns the converted date as a formatted string using the locale of the context user. If the time zone cannot be determined, GMT is used.**

I hope your expectations is you need hour value for any Timezone, If so you directly use

```
String x = DateTime.Now(timeFormat,TimeZoneSidKey);
```

Then you can split it

You can use below piece of code

```
Datetime myNowGMTTime = DateTime.Now();
System.debug('myNowGMTTime--->'+myNowGMTTime);
//But if i Use format it will show my current TimeZone time
String myTimeWithMyTimeZone = DateTime.now().format();
System.debug('myTimeWithMyTimeZone--->'+myTimeWithMyTimeZone);


/* NOW COMING TO YOUR QUESTION  , IF YOUR EXPECTATIONS IS YOU NEED HOUR VALUE FOR A PARTICULAR TIMEZONE 
   BELOW IS THE CODE ----------------*/
String americaChicagoTime =Datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss','America/Chicago');
System.debug('americaChicagoTime--->'+americaChicagoTime);

String americaChicagoTimeHour=americaChicagoTime.split(' ')[1].split(':')[0];
System.debug('americaChicagoTimeHour--->'+americaChicagoTimeHour);
```

[image]